# MySQL - timestamp in where clause

Tags: mysql, timestamp, where-clause

I've had a good dig around and while I can find hints on how to achieve this I can't quite get to see the full solution.

I have a table (t_splits) in which records get streamed in from multiple sources. Each row contains an ID (split_id - auto-increment), a time (split_time) in the format HH:MM:SS (which is time local to where the record originated) and a timestamp column (inserted_ts - which is, obv, the time the record was inserted).

This table is populated over time via a socket-server listening for these streams.

What I want to then do is to select any records that were inserted more than, say, 10 seconds ago sorted by HH:MM:SS column earliest time first.

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     t_splits
WHERE    ?? (something to do with inserted_ts and Now and the 10 sec delay) 
ORDER BY ?? (something using HH, MM & SS)
```

It will be a bit more complicated in real life but that's the basic setup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Nymor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT * from t_splits WHERE insert_ts < date_sub(now(),interval 10 second)
 order by   insert_ts ;
```

( assuming "earliest time" means oldest first )

Comment: Thanks DhruvPathak - didn't know about the Interval. I need to sort by the HH:MM:Ss column so what I think I'll do is add another column with the HH:MM:SS time in seconds and sort by that instead.